# Python gRPC client usage

Tags: python, multithreading, grpc

Having a gRPC service deployed somewhere I now need to communicate with it so I create a client/stub. Let's assume the other service - the client of the gRPC service is a Uwsgi deployed service. I'm wondering since one of the benefits is that with gRPC (HTTP/2) I can make multiple requests in one TCP connection:

When is the TCP connection created? I assume it's when I initialize the stub, is that right?

Should I create one shared stub for all Uwsgi threads so they can all use that one TCP connection? If so how lost connections are handled? Do I need to handle those?
Or should I initialize the stub for every request and then benefit from the shared TCP connection only if I need to talk to the gRPC service multiple times in one Uwsgi request?

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: hi @McAbra: Did you get an answer for it? I am hitting a wall in writing a client in Python for a gRPC service written in Java.

Comment: Sadly not, I ended up deeming gRPC not yet mature enough to use in the platform I was working on.